# display browser window width using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like my PHP script to be able to access the width of the browser window. I've been reading up on this, and PHP can't access this information itself, but Javascript/jQuery can, and can then pass it to the server using AJAX, so PHP can get at it.

Following a few solutions online I've written the following test file, and called it "test.php"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<?php
if (!isset($_POST["window_width"])) {
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "window_width="+window_width,
    });
</script>   

<?php
}

if(!isset($_POST["window_width"])) {
    echo "not set";
}

?>
</html>
```

Loading test.php displays "not set" which shows that the window_width variable is not being picked up by PHP. This seems weird to me, because Firebug shows that the variable is there (set at 1366 on my computer, as this is the width of my browser).

How can I ensure that $_POST["window_width"] is set so that I can access it using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use ajax in this case, the 'outer' (?) page needs to receive the data, not the 'inner' ajax request.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<?php
if (!isset($_POST["window_width"]) && !isset($_SESSION['window_width'])) {
?>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="window_width_form" style="display:none;">
<input name="window_width" id="window_width" value="" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#window_width').val($(window).width());
        $('#window_width_form').submit();
    });
</script>   
</body>
<?php
}
elseif (isset($_POST['window_width']) && !isset($_SESSION['window_width']))
{
    $_SESSION['window_width'] = $_POST['window_width'];
    exit(header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}\r\n"));
}

if(!isset($_POST["window_width"]) && !isset($_SESSION['window_width'])) {
    echo "not set";
}

?>
</html>
```

Comment: I've just updated this to hide the form, very briefly you will see 'not set' in the browser, then the form submits and it dissapears, hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Dale,

This helps, but I'm not sure it's the best practice solution for my problem. One issue is that if I refresh the page I get a Firefox message telling me that "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

I can't really have a situation where the user sees this everytime they refresh my page

Comment: I did think about that! You could add an `if (isset($_POST['window_width']))` or something along those lines, to then update a session value, and check `if (!isset($_POST['window_width']) || !isset($_SESSION['window_width']))`

Comment: The way I mentioned would then work for the rest of the session life, but what if they resize their browser window?

Comment: yes, I thought about a session variable too, but would really like the value to be updated if the user resized their browser window

Comment: I have added the code to now maintain a session! The next bit is beyond the scope of your question :-) hang on I've broken something

Comment: OK it's fixed now, it wasn't broken I forgot to check for the session value in the final if :-)

Comment: thanks. this gives me something to work with from here, so i'm going to accept your answer. could you accept my question?

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

I dont understand whats you goal ist but it looks like you forgot to wait till the DOM is ready.

#### Sample

```
$(function() {
   var window_width = $(window).width();
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: "window_width="+window_width,
   });
});
```

Comment: My goal is simply for PHP to be able to access the browser width in my PHP file, but maybe I'm going about it the wrong way...

I tried putting your code in place of mine, but I got the same result. How can I wait until the DOM is ready? I don't really understand what this means

Comment: You can call another page with ajax and pass in the window width to save it to the session or do something else with it. Could you provide a better sample ?

Comment: I just [tested on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bpjE/). The window width is available before the DOM is ready, so this won't help.

Comment: @dknaack

My usecase is that I am displaying products on a page, and each product has a fixed width. I want to determine the window width on pageload and then use that to determine how many products to display so that no more than 2 rows of products are displayed. Maybe there is a better solution that passing the page width to PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Your server side code doesn't pause processing to wait for the JavaScript to run. You are dealing with two separate HTTP requests here.

1. The browser requests the HTML document
2. Since `$_POST['window_width']` is not set for that request. PHP returns an HTML document that includes the script. Since `$_POST['window_width']` is *still* not set for that request, it also echos *not set*.
3. The browser receives the HTTP response and parses it. As part of this process, it runs the JavaScript.
4. The JavaScript makes a POST request to … wherever jQuery sends requests to by default since you didn't include a URI (which a very quick test suggests is the current URI).
5. For this request `$_POST["window_width"]` is set and included in the document returned to JavaScript.
6. Since the JavaScript doesn't have a `success` handler (or any other code that runs when the HTTP request comes back) the browser doesn't do anything with that document.

Ajax is a shorthand way of saying "Talk to the webserver with JavaScript". It doesn't stop HTTP being a stateless Request-Response protocol.

You haven't stated your usecase for getting the window width (which can change after the page has loaded), so it is hard to suggest a good solution to whatever problem you have.  (You appear to have asked an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

The two common reasons for wanting to know the window width are:

- Statistics — in which case you can just process the data in PHP and not worry about rendering it to the client
- Changing the layout — which is usually better achieved with CSS media queries

Comment: ok, thanks. what is the best way to handle this? I load test.php, and I want to use jQuery to find the browser width. then i need PHP to be able to access this, which is why I used the AJAX code. would you be able to post some sample code so the server code waits for the JavaScript to run?

Comment: Hi, thanks for this reply. I understand everything except point 6.

My usecase is that I'm displaying products on a page, and I want to display no more than 2 rows of products. Each product is 140px in width, and so my plan is to fetch the window width, and determine how many products to show so that no more than 2 rows are displayed.

Comment: I think that this could probably be done using CSS, but someone else did the front-end coding for me, because I don't know CSS

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$.ajax({
        url : "your url goes here"
        type: "POST",
        data: {"window_width":window_width}
    });
```

Comment: nope, this didn't help (i set the url as the name of the file, "test.php")

Comment: I did a test. jQuery appears to default to the current URI if you don't specify one explicitly (presumably it handles it as a relative URI ""), so adding an explicit URI wouldn't help with the code as it is written.

Comment: To whoever down voted, I tried to help! But this is not a potentially wrong answer which could lead to unexpected result!